# adding wildcard to look up formula?

Tags: excel

I am using the following formula as part of a multi result look up function. I have several of these formulas posted into one row each beneath the other, so if I type `catering` into cell `K22` on sheet 1 my formula then looks up that matching word from column `b` on sheet 2 and produces the name in column `a`.
 The formula also includes duplicating this lookup a few times to fetch other values from other columns with the same matching result.

so for instance my columns on sheet 2 look like:

```
Name     Description       Location      Number
Amy      hotel             london        1
Dave     hotels            manchester    2
Mike     catering          Birmingham    3
```

What I want to do is to use wild cards around my cell `K22` in this formula to show if the descripion word I type in is like hotel; i.e. hotels, hote ... etc then find the result?
...
I know this can be done using index match but can I use them with the following code I have? at the moment this is an array formula but I get no result when I try to do it like this. can someone show me where I am going wrong, tanks

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$7,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$7="*"&Sheet1!$K$22&"*",ROW($B$1:$B$7)),ROW(1:1)),1)),"",INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$7,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$7="*"&Sheet1!$K$22&"*",ROW($B$1:$B$7)),ROW(1:1)),1)) & " - " &IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$7,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$7="*"&Sheet1!$K$22&"*",ROW($B$1:$B$7)),ROW(1:1)),3)),"",INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$7,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$7="*"&Sheet1!$K$22&"*",ROW($B$1:$B$7)),ROW(1:1)),3)) & " - " &IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$7,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$7="*"&Sheet1!$K$22&"*",ROW($B$1:$B$7)),ROW(1:1)),4)),"",INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$7,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$7="*"&Sheet1!$K$22&"*",ROW($B$1:$B$7)),ROW(1:1)),4
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you **can** use wildcards in the lookup value within a `MATCH` function (and in other contexts), you can't use them here. When using wildcards with a direct comparison with `=` like you have, i.e.

`Sheet2!$B$1:$B$7="*"&Sheet1!$K$22&"*"`

the * is interpreted as a literal asterisk not a wildcard

Replace all instance of the above with this

`ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$K$22,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$7))`